# Stuck using facebook php sdk. GetUser always returns 0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have got this code to login with the user if there is not anyone.

index.php, located in http://DOMAIN.COM/PATH.

Here, if the user id returned is 0, the login url is taken from facebook instance and a redirection is made to that url to login with a facebook user. Then, after the authorize action, the next url iss "http://DOMAIN.COM/PATH/check.php" where the "getUser" method is again executed, however, the user id is 0 again.

`

```
$fbPermissions = 'read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos';
$site_url   = "http://DOMAIN.COM/PATH/check.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
            'appId'  => 'MY_ID',  
            'secret' => 'MY_SECRET_ID',   
            'cookie' => true  
            ));  

$user = $facebook->getUser(); 

if($user) { 

    try{  
            echo "user id insid if=".$user;
            $user = $facebook->api('/me');  
    } catch (Exception $e){}  

} else {  
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$fbPermissions,'redirect_uri'=>$site_url));
    header('location:'.$loginUrl.'');
} 
?>
```

Code of check.php

```
<?php
include_once("facebook.php");

$fbPermissions = 'read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
            'appId'  => 'MY_ID',  
            'secret' => 'MY_SECRET_ID',  
            'cookie' => true  
            ));  

$user = $facebook->getUser(); 

if($user) { 

    try{  
            echo "user id insid if=".$user;
            $user = $facebook->api('/me');  
    } catch (Exception $e){}  

} else {  
    echo "No user";
} 
?>
```

Thus, in options in my app of facebook developers page, I have the "
Site URL" option with this value "http://DOMAIN.COM/PATH/". I have had to create a Website platform in "configuration" section.

I am working in a internet hosting not in localhost.

Which can be the problem? I am really stuck

Comment: can u try this $user = $facebook->getUser();  inside try catch block and display the Exception

Comment: here is answer to your question, That's a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/a/25671780/612987

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The code is correct. The problem was one o several options of the facebook app. I am not sure what was the option that I changed, I put the probably options of my app in order to help this common problem.

Web Site App.

Stream post URL security => Off
Native or desktop app? => Off

Hope its helps, this problems is really common how it's seen if you search with this topic.

Comment: Native or desktop app? => Off  solved my problem thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your PHP version? Is it 5.4.x?
If so then you need to change the PHP SDK code a little bit.

I have had the same problem with you and I found this article really help me a a lot.
[facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x/)

Answer (score 0):

Its Happen to me and when i check my Apache log i found this :

[image]

And i found its an SSL problems when communicate with Facebook via PHP SDK (using Curl). You have to set CURL_OPTS "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" to "false" .

Ex:

```
facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but i just solved my similar problem `(->getUser() = 0)`.

First, i'm using the *Facebook SDK 3.x.x* (that requires PHP 5.2) and not the *latest Facebook SDK 4.0* (that requires PHP 5.4). Till now i've just used/included 2 files of the SDK (`facebook.php` and `base_facebook.php`) and, for some reason, ignored the 3rd certificate file named `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt`.

The result was that while i logged-in normally (through `->getLoginUrl()` and a custom JS *popup* window), facebook api was always given me **=0** on `->getUser()` call, even if i was able to surf to facebook and verify i was truly connected through my own popup.

That until i decided to look over my apache logs and to find that, **astonishingly descriptive error** of `'Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information'`. I quickly searched facebook SDK code and found that message is related to the above **.crt** file.

*After i included the file* in the same folder as the 2 above, my `->getUser()` call was able to return my facebook account information.

Answer (score 0):

simple understandable code of SDK 4.0 integration with PHP is here https://github.com/ssgaur/Facebook-Login-PHP-SDK-v4