# facebook connect- $user_id = $facebook->getUser(); always returning 0

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

Before i say something i want to say that i GOOGLEd a lot and there were lots of pages found(including many of so's question) with varieties of solutions ... but i have tried each of them one by one but unfortunately none of them worked for me

with facebook-php-sdk i am trying to login a user. **on first few occasions it was working perfectly fine (2 to 3 days ago.)**. **Today when i started again working with my project its not working any more**.whenever i am trying to login a user `$facebook->getUser() is returning 0`.Buts 3 days back it was working.

i have used the code given here :: **[developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi)** and yes i have made some changes those are given with the full code below

MY CODE :: **`0auth_provided_by_facebook.php`**

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dist/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$config = array(
   'appId' => '***********',
   'secret' => '*********',
   'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
'cookie'    => true,
'oauth'     => true
 );

 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 if($user_id) {
   try {

      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   scope'=>'email,user_location,user_photos,publish_actions,publish_stream,basic_info', 
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php'
    ));
    echo '<a href="' . $login_url .'"> PLEASE CLICK HERE </a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'     => 'email,user_location,user_photos,publish_actions,publish_stream,basic_info', 
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php'
    ));
  echo '<a href="' . $login_url .'"> PLEASE CLICK HERE </a>';

}
```

OUTPUT : getUser() is always returning 0.

---

**how my login process works described below :**

after clicking on `<a href="login_fb">Login using fb </a>` control goes to my `localhost/dist/index.php` now my index.php `include` the above wriiten code which is in different directory `localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php` from this file i handle everything. on successful and failure of login facebook returns value here.and then on successful login user is again redirected to home

---

Now here is he full list of my app setting which i enabled or disabled or changed

```
 1. App Domains : blank(according to the answer)
 2. Site URL : `http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php?` 
 3. Native or desktop app? Disabled
 4. Deauthorize Callback URL : `http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php?`
 5. Social Discovery : enabled
 6. Client OAuth Login : enabled
 7. Embedded browser OAuth Login :enabled
 8. App Secret Proof for Server API calls :enabled
 9. Require 2-factor reauthorization : disabled
10. Valid OAuth redirect URIs :`http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php?` (according to the suggesion given in the answer)
11. Stream post URL security : enabled
```

these were the details. `$user_id = $facebook-> getUser();` is always returning `0` in all condition. how can i solve it?

---

for more info .. thhough i dont know it will help you not...i was going through my base_facebook.php and i found that it is returning zero because of `if(signed_request)`is always false.

Comment: Why do you have the deauth callback same target with the site?

Comment: Does the user authorize your app? Does the flow happen and still you get user id 0 ? Is that correct? Is that your problem ?

Comment: yes the user authorize my app ... it is mentioned in roles in developers.facebook.com .... and

>still you get user id 0 ? Is that correct? 
yes thats my problem

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this issue you need to do the following

Change

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'     => 'email,user_location,user_photos,publish_actions,basic_info', 
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/dist/'
    ));
```

to

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'     => 'email,user_location,user_photos,publish_actions,basic_info', 
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/dist/index.php'
    ));
```

Leave domain name blank in the following setting. Dont give localhost.com

```
App Domains : localhost.com
```

Then

```
Valid OAuth redirect URIs :http://localhost/dist/
```

to

```
Valid OAuth redirect URIs :`http://localhost/dist/index.php
```

Now try there after.

Comment: can you check itr again please..not working

Answer (score 0):

change your app secret from app configuration page.then use this new app secret in above page you have mentioned.Delete all the cookies in browser and try loading the page you will get the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

to me it sounds issue of local host if you can use a domain to test your code i have a one page login system running on my website i can send you all code how ever you code is looking good.

Answer (score 0):

Edit base_facebook.php library and replace existing `getCode()` function with

```
protected function getCode() {
$server_info = array_merge($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE);
    if (isset($server_info['code'])) {
        if ($this->state !== null && isset($server_info['state']) && $this->state === $server_info['state']) {
            $this->state = null;
            $this->clearPersistentData('state');
            return $server_info['code'];
        } else {
            self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```